# CouchDB keys query on view much slower than keys query on _all_docs

Tags: couchdb

I'm attempting to fetch about 900 keys in a single request from a javascript view which takes about 6-7 seconds. The index is fully built and no documents are being inserted into the database. When I do a the same type of keys request to the `_all_docs` view, it returns in less than half a second. I was under the impression that the `_all_docs` view is just like any other and I'm confused by the massive difference in performance. I am setting `include_docs=true` and I would expect the lookups in the index would be something like `900 * log(n)` and then the overhead of 900 fetches for the documents themselves. Is there something about the CouchDB architecture I'm not understanding that would account for the difference?

For example this is what is taking 6-7 seconds:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request "POST"  --data '{"keys":[...900 keys...]}' http://couch/database/_design/ddoc/_view/view?include_docs=true&reduce=false&group=false
```

This is near instant:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request "POST"  --data '{"keys":[...900 keys...]}' http://couch/database/_all_docs?include_docs=true&reduce=false&group=false
```

*Edit*

Here is the view we are using.
It emits an array of a `participantId` and `docType`.

```
function (doc) { 
    if (doc.participantId) { emit([doc.participantId, doc.docType]) }

    if (doc.participantIds) {
        doc.participantIds.forEach(function(participantId) {
            emit([participantId, doc.docType])
        })
    }
}
```

The keys in the query looks like this:

```
{"keys":[['id1', 'TYPE1'], ['id1', 'TYPE2'], ['id2', 'TYPE1'], etc...]}
```

*Edit 2*

Here is a snippet I dropped into the console while using fauxton that nicely demonstrates the problem. It queries the view with a set of keys and logs a timer, then queries the same documents by the ids with a timer. I consistently see the first request taking 6-7 seconds and the second request taking less than a second. For the same exact documents. Looking through the actual CouchDB Erland code it does seem that an _all_docs query is treated differently and possibly not the same as a regular b-tree search which would explain the difference.

```
function test(keys) {
    var s = Date.now()
    fetch('/databaose/_design/ddoc/_view/view?include_docs=true&reduce=false&group=false', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({'keys': keys})
    }).then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
        console.log('Took ' + (Date.now() - s) + ' ms.')
        console.log(r)
        return r
    }).then(r => {
        s = Date.now()
        return fetch('/experience/_all_docs?include_docs=true&reduce=false&group=false', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({'keys': r.rows.map(row => row.id)})
        }).then(r => r.json()).then(r => {
            console.log('Took ' + (Date.now() - s) + ' ms.')
            console.log(r)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Post your design document.

Comment: `_all_docs` is like any other view, in that it's just an index. But without seeing your custom index, it's impossible to know if it's efficient or should perform the same.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I updated the question with the view document and a more concrete example of the keys query.

Comment: Well one obvious reason your view is likely slower: It appears to be potentially magnitudes larger than `_all_docs`. `_all_docs` contains exactly one entry per document. Yours contains one for each instance of `participantId` and `participantIds`. How many instances of those exist per doc, on average?

Comment: Indeed I am fallible but I do not believe the keys query provided to `_all_docs` would only ever return errors?

Comment: as it stands the view actually has about the same amount of documents as the _all_docs index

Comment: The keys query to _all_docs does work.

Comment: for reference both  views have about 1.4 million documents

Comment: If the data you seek can be had from `_all_docs` then why is there a discussion about creating a view? I'm quite confused, and I'll have to reproduce myself to believe as much.

Comment: I updated the question again that makes it easy to re-produce the example. The reason I'm using a view is to query a bunch of documents by `participantId` and `docType` instead of `_id`. That view query by keys is going quite slow, but querying the exact same documents by `_all_docs` is much much faster. I'm just confused by the disparity in performance when they are both just views supposedly. I suspect `_all_docs` queries are not the same type of b-tree search though.